# How to unit test LiveData Transformations

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-livedata, mockk

I clearly don't understand how to unit test business logic inside Transformation. In my specific case I need to test `Transformations.map`, but I guess `Transformations.switchmap` would be the same.

The following is just an example of my scenario, and what I'd like to achieve.

#### MyViewModel.kt

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {

private val _sampleLiveDataIwannaTest : MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()
val sampleLiveDataIWannaTest: Livedata<Int> = _sampleLiveDataIWannaTest

// ...

val liveDataImNotInterestedIn = Transformations.map(myRepository.streamingData){ 
     streaming->

      _sampleLiveDataIwannaTest.postValue(streaming.firstElementValue +streaming.lastElementValue)

      streaming
  }
// ...
}
```

With:

```
val liveDataImNotInteresedIn : LiveData<Foo>

myRepository.streamingData : LiveData<Foo>
```

`myRepository.streamingData` is a data source that wakes up the `Transformations.map` which, in turn, starts the business logic I'm interested in (the value posted in `_sampleLiveDataIwannaTest`). In this particular test, I don't care about anything else.

#### MyViewModelTest.kt

```
class MyViewModelTest {
    @get:Rule    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @RelaxedMockK
    lateinit var myRepository : MyRepository

    @OverrideMockKs
    lateinit var sut: MyViewModel

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxUnitFun = true)
    }

    @Test
    fun Transformations_Test(){

        sut.liveDataImNotInterestedIn.observeForever{}

      // 1)I really don't know how to mock the livedata that returns from 
      //     myRepository.streamingData . Something like this is correct?
      //        every{myRepository.streamingData}.returns{< LiveData of type Int > }

     // 2) I wish to write this kind of test: 
     //
     // assertEquals(5, sampleLiveDataIWannaTest.value)

    }
```

I'm using MockK instead of Mockito.

Comment: Did you find ay solution? For me I got error when try to create live data in every{ } return liveData{} will crash with message:
tried to access class androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper from class androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$Subclass0

Answer (score 0):

The unit test code will look like this:

```
class MyViewModelTest {
@get:Rule
val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

@RelaxedMockK
lateinit var myRepository : MyRepository

@RelaxedMockK
lateinit var mockedSampleLiveDataIWannaTest : Observer<Int>

@OverrideMockKs
lateinit var sut: MyViewModel


@Before
fun setUp() {
    MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxUnitFun = true)
}


@Test
fun Transformations_Test(){
    val expected = (*YOUR EXPECTED DATA HERE FROM REPOSITORY*)

    every { myRepository.streamingData() } answers { expected }
    sut.sampleLiveDataIWannaTest.observeForever(mockedSampleLiveDataIWannaTest)

    verify { myRepository.streamingData() }
    verify() { mockedSampleLiveDataIWannaTest.onChanged(Int) }
    confirmVerified(myRepository, mockedSampleLiveDataIWannaTest)

}
```

if your repository is using coroutines then change `every` to `coEvery` and `verify` to `coVerify`

to learn more about MockK: https://mockk.io/

Comment: I think problem is can not return liveData for mocking like every{} return liveData{} will crash!